# php getting value from object

Tags: php

I've got basic array from my api:

```
{ "title": "offer title", "body": "offer body", 
"specialities": { "lang": "en", "id": "1", "icon": "0",
"name": "speciality name 1" }, "region": "region1" }
```

I want to get `id` value from request for my php variable lets say: `$idVariable`. How can I do it?

I tried something like:

```
$idVariable = $request->specialities[0]->id
```

but it seems not working. What is the right way?

Then how should I work with the arrays of object in this case:

```
{ "title": "offer title", "body": "offer body", 
"specialities": [
{ "lang": "en", "id": "1", "icon": "0", "name": "speciality name 1" },
 { "lang": "en", "id": "2", "icon": "0", "name": "speciality name 2" },
 { "lang": "en", "id": "2", "icon": "0", "name": "speciality name 3" },
 etc...], "region": "region1" }
```

To get id's of every object in specialities array? I know that it could be a duplicate question, but I ask for just a basic example.

I tried to use json decode like below:

```
json_decode($request->get('specialties'))->id
```

edit:

The almost-right way to do it is to decode json file first:

```
$data = json_decode($request);
```

and then get the right property from the array:

```
$id = $data['specialities'][0]['id'];
```

the problem now is that id is a string not an integer and by simply using:

```
$int_id = intval($id)
```

I've got $int_id = `0` instead of `1`,`2`,`3` etc

Comment: Define **not working**... Did you `json_decode` the result?

Comment: Show me what you have tried by **editing the question and not posting the code as a comment**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a response from API in [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) you should use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then use the data. Try this code.

```
$json = '{ "title": "offer title", "body": "offer body", 
"specialities": { "lang": "en", "id": "1", "icon": "0",
"name": "speciality name 1" }, "region": "region1" }';

$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->specialities->id;
```

Comment: this should work but I've got `"message": "Trying to get property of non-object",`  my code is: `$data = json_decode($request);`  `$offer->specialities()->sync($data->specialities->id, false);`

Comment: might be your response data has not a valid data? check your data before trying to get property like `if ($data->specialities) { // Now get property if the object is available}`

Comment: got the same error within if statement

Comment: @gileneusz might be your object does not have the property. Please check your response data.